# CosmsDB Query on Date Field

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, date-range

When I run the following query on AZure portal, it runs fine but when ran programmatically from a .NET App, it gives an error:

Raw query on Azure CosmosDB portal: `SELECT * FROM c where c.OrderDateTime > '2018-11-29T18:33:17.5957307Z'` Works fine

```
string queryString = $"SELECT * FROM c  Where c.OrderDateTime >= '{DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1).ToString("s")}'"; Gives the following error:
```

Message:

> {\"Errors\":[\"An invalid query has been specified with filters
>   against path(s) that are not range-indexed. Consider adding allow scan
>   header in the request.\"]}

I understand Dates in range query needs different handling than strings, but was wondering how it can work on the portal? Am I missing something else in my code?

Comment: How is your index policy? The error you're receiving indicates that the query engine could not find a range index for the path c.OrderDateTime.

Comment: @JayGong Indexing is numbers range and strings hash, but nothing for DateTime.

Comment: So, maybe you need to add strings range index for `OrderDataTime` column,please have a try?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {\"Errors\":[\"An invalid query has been specified with filters
>   against path(s) that are not range-indexed. Consider adding allow scan
>   header in the request.\"]}

The error you're receiving here indicates that the query engine could not find a range index for the path C.OrderDateTime . Please check the `Indexing Policy` of you collection and make sure that both numbers and strings are indexed as range rather than hash. For more information about indexing policies, please see [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy).

Or you could set `EnableScanInQuery` as true in `FeedOptions` follow the error `details:Consider adding allow scan header in the request`. Please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#indexing-modes).

```
var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
{
   EnableScanInQuery = true,
};
```

As I know, SQL Query on the portal is different from sdk query or rest api query. It will have some implicit optimizations, such as not having to provide a partition key to execute a query on a partition key column.That doesn't mean the partition key doesn't need to be provided in client side query operation.